# Mysql select row having only specified values in a column

Tags: mysql

Hi I have this mysql table named student_subject_table:

```
+----+-------------+---------------------+ 
| id | student_id  | subject             | 
+----+-------------+---------------------+ 
|  1 |           7 | math                | 
|  2 |           7 | physics             |  
|  3 |           7 | chemistry           |  
|  8 |           8 | math                | 
|  9 |           8 | physics             | 
| 10 |           8 | chemistry           | 
| 11 |           8 | biology             |  
+----+-------------+---------------------+
```

I am trying to get the ids of student those who have only math, physics and chemistry as subject.

I tried in clause:

```
 select student_id
 from student_subject table
 where
   subject in ('math', 'physics', 'chemistry')
 GROUP BY (student_id)
```

As expected I am getting both 7 and 8 as student_id.
In the above table I need only student_id = 7.

Is there any way in mysql I can do this ?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this query:

```
select student_id
from student_subject table
group by student_id
having
  SUM(subject IN ('math', 'physics', 'chemistry')) = COUNT(DISTINCT subject)
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT subject)=3
```

- `SUM(subject IN ('math', 'physics', 'chemistry'))` will be 3 for both student 7 and 8
- `COUNT(DISTINCT subject)` will be 3 for student 7 and 4 for student 8

if `(student_id, subject)` is unique, you can replace `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` with `COUNT(*)`.

only student 7 will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCT Clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id 
FROM student_subject_table 
WHERE subject IN ('math', 'physics', 'chemistry') 
GROUP BY (student_id);
```